# MVC 3 action get parameter as null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I serialize `Fpr,` and post it to the server using jquery.
in the action method, I try go get a `List<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` of the `object` but the `List<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` is null.
How to post it to the method so i will get it as List or `IEnumerable`.

```
var div = $("#TableForm").serialize();
$.post("../Controller/Action?Mode=" + Mode, div , function () { });
```

I serialize the form and the serialize is OK. The problem is only in the action - that i got null, please help

Comment: Please provide the jQuery code and your action method signature.

Comment: Is the name of the variable that you are posting the same as the parameter in the action method? Also, I don't understand -- you're serializing an html table and trying to pass that in? I'm not sure that will work.

Comment: 'var A = $("#TableForm").serialize();'

Comment: there is an Inputs in every td in the table that are object. i concatenate every object and pass it to the action. i want it to be IEnumerable.

Comment: public void AddPlacedJson(IEnumerable<CafePlaced> PlacedPCK, string Mode)

Comment: Adam, please edit your question to indicate what you added in the comments, and please add the code that does the ajax POSTing.

Comment: Please add sample.code for Jquery you use in your view and the appropriate action method.

Comment: Someone gave you a -1, but I countered it because the OP is starting to show some effort. Please now add some of the field names in your table, and some of the fields in your ViewModel (`CafePlaced`) to receive more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can't serialize a `table` object:

HTML:

```
​<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td><input id='one' name='one' value='blah' /></td>
        <td><input id='two' name='two' value='moreblah' /></td>
    </tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JavaScript:

```
var serialized = ​$("#myTable").serialize();
debugger;​​​​​
```

When the code pauses in the debugger, you can see that `serialized` is `""`, the empty string. MVC won't know how to model bind this to your IEnumerable, so it is null.

On the other hand, if you do this:

```
var serialized = ​$("#one, #two").serialize();
debugger;​​​​​
```

Then `serialized` will be equal to `"one=blah&two=moreblah"`.

Second, if you're actually binding to a `form` then all input elements inside the table will be correctly serialized. **However**, the names of your input elements are extremely important since you are trying to model-bind to an `IEnumerable<CafePlaced>`. Read this article by Phil Haack on model binding to a list: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

If you don't do it correctly, then MVC won't know how to model bind and your parameter will come through as null.

Comment: The serialized is not empty, it's full of all the code in the table, any way in the controller it seems to be null

Comment: So you are serializing a `form`, not a `table`?

Comment: at first i've tried a form then a table, and the both are not working

Comment: It's important to understand that if i serialize the table and in the action i expect to get just one object it work OK

Comment: Pandincus, I serialize the form and the serialize is OK. The problem is only in the action - that i got null, please help

Comment: Did you read the Phil Haack article on model binding to a list?

Comment: Thanks  Pandincus, it's working the way they explain in the article!!